# Realizar mysqli INTO table VALORES, con los valores de un array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, array, base-de-datos

**Tengo los valores recogidos desde un formulario dinámico en un ARRAY.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function multiplicarInputs(text) {
    var num= text.value
    var div='';
    for (var i=0;i<num;i++) { 
        var cont=i+1;
        div+="<br> Nombre de Opción "+cont+"<input maxlength='100' name='inputTextMulti[]' size='6' type='text' />&nbsp;";
        //div+="<br> Precio de Opción "+cont+"<input maxlength='100' name='inputTextMulti[]2' size='6' type='text' />&nbsp;";
    }
    document.getElementById("divMultiInputs").innerHTML=div;
} 
</script>
```

**Segundo paso**

Ahora quiero que cada paso del ciclo for, haga una consulta msqli INSERT INTO options_values VALUES..., es decir si el Array tiene 5 valores, pues que haga 5 INSERT a mi tabla.
Lo intento con este código pero no me funciona.

```
if(isset($_POST['crear'])) {
    $inputs=($_POST['inputTextMulti']);
    $corchetes= count($inputs);
    for ($i=0; $i[$corchetes]; $i++) {
        $cont=$i+1;
        $valores = $inputs[$i];
        $tabla2 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO options_values (id_inputs,value) VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID(inputs)','implode($valores)')");
        alert("Formulario Añadido con Exito",1,'agregar_extra');
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que donde pone `for ($i=0; $i[$corchetes];` debería poner: `for ($i=0; $i <= $corchetes;`

Comment: **Gracias, he conseguido que funcione la primera parte ya que hasta ahora tan solo traía desde el formulario un solo input con el metodo $_POST,pero en realidad quiero traer dos inputs. Dejo el código tal y como funciona ahora y como está planteado para que haga tambien la subida del segundo input. No sé si seré capaz de hacerlo utilizando lo que tengo, o tendré que cambiar de ciclo para utilizar los dos inputs. Abajo he creado una respuesta a mi pregunta con el nuevo código.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido que funcione la primera parte ya que hasta ahora tan solo traía desde el formulario un solo input con el método `$_POST`, pero en realidad quiero traer dos inputs.
Dejo el código tal y como funciona ahora y como está planteado para que haga tambien la subida del segundo input.
No sé si seré capaz de hacerlo utilizando lo que tengo, o tendré que cambiar de ciclo para utilizar los dos inputs.

```
<?php
if ($tabla1==true) {
    $inputs=array_merge(($_POST['inputTextMulti']),($_POST['inputTextMulti2']));
    $corchetes= count($inputs);
      
    for ($i=0; $i < $corchetes; $i++) {
        $valores = $inputs[$i];
        $precios = $inputs[$i];
        $tabla2 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO options_values (id_inputs,value,price) VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID(inputs)','$valores','$precios')");
    }
}
?>
```

Evidentemente con este código no tan solo consigo llenar las dos columnas de mi tabla con la misma información cuando lo que quiero es que el primer dato del array `($_POST['inputTextMulti'])`, se aloje en la columna a la que va la variable `$valores`. Y que el primer dato del array `($_POST['inputTextMulti2'])`, se aloje en la columna a la que va la variable `$precios`. Y así sucesivamente mientras que queden elementos en los arrays.
En el formulario ya está estipulado, que siempre hayan la misma cantidad de elementos en los dos arrays.